# List of useful `less` functions

Tags: command-line, less

Rather than ask for your favorite, lets just list them off.

What are the more useful commands inside `less`?

Personally, I use:

- `/` (search forward)
- `?` (search backwards)
- `F` (enable    tail -f like behvaior,
  Ctrl-C to    break out of it)
- `v`    (open file in $EDITOR for editing, defaults to vi/vim)

Others?

Comment: For the record `v` opens `$EDITOR` with local file - not necessary vi/vim.

Comment: Edited in that change!  Thanks Maciej!  I did not know that one!

Answer (score 11):

One can also use the mark feature to remember (and jump back to) specific positions in the file.

For example, type `ma` to mark a position with the label `"a"`. To jump back to the position, simply type `'a`. Labels can be any alphabet (case sensitive) thus allowing up to 52 possible marks ([a-zA-Z]) although I seldom use more than 2.

Comment: Awesome!  I needed that feature and did not know it existed!

Comment: Also useful (from the man page) is that if you jump somewhere (eg, with 'g'), you can jump back with '' (double apostrophe).

Answer (score 7):

- `u` - up half page
- `d` - down half page
- `k` - scroll single line up
- `j` - scroll single line down
- `-i` - case insensitive searching unless pattern contains capitals (as clo or in less)
- `/ /pattern/` - search (used with n)
- `-p /pattern/` open file at /pattern/ (as clo)
- `& /pattern/` show lines containing /pattern/ (like grep)

Comment: ? /pattern/ - search backwards (also used with n)

 F - Follow like tail -f

Comment: As i recall it, `&pattern` shows ONLY lines that contain /pattern/ ?

Comment: @lsc:  Yes, that's right.  I've updated.

Answer (score 6):

`-S` (either at the command line or typing `-` and `S` while running `less`) chops long lines and is helpful when viewing e.g. log files. Type `-` and `S` again to switch back.

Answer (score 5):

Other than the obvious, my two favorites:

1. `export LESS=-FX` - if there is under one page, I don't need to press `q` to quit
2. Type `/^HEADING` to search for headings and `/^ *-option` to search for options
   (especially useful in the bash man page, which in very large)

Comment: +1 for LESS=-FX, just what i wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- ^f - page down
- ^b - page up
- G - go to the end of buffer
- gg - go to the beginning of the buffer

also - most of them are just vim-like functions for navigation.

Comment: I use `space` for page down, `b` for back a page (page up).  `g` for beginning, `G` for the end as well.

Comment: Don't forget: `42g` - go to line number 42.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a function inside of `less`, but it is a useful feature.

I like man pages, and prefer [less(1)](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/) as my pager. However, most GNU software keeps the manual in the [info(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info_%28Unix%29) (GNU Texinfo) format, and I'm not a fan of the info(1) interface. Just give me less.

So, I read info(1) pages using `less` instead. The following command will print out the info(1) pages, using the familiar interface of less!

```
info gpg |less
```

Answer (score 2):

- `n` - continue searching for your pattern in the same direction
- `N` - continue searching for your pattern in the opposite direction

If you started searching for 'foo' and want to keep finding instances of it, you can hit `/` followed by return over and over, or you can just hit `n` (with no return) to keep on searching in the same direction.

- `-N` - show line numbers
- `-I` - ignore case in your search pattern (useful when looking for errors that might be spelled as 'ERROR|Error|error')
- `-G` - turn off highlighting

You can type those while less is already viewing a file and they'll take affect on whatever file you're viewing. You can undo them by typing them again.

Answer (score 1):

Although it took a [question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16594/6403) to remind me how to do it, I always liked the `-e` or `--quit-at-eof` option of `less`.

This nominally causes any page down at the end of the file to quit out of `less`, but has the useful side effect that if you specified multiple files, it also causes a page down at the end of one file to take you on to the next. That can save loads of `:n`'s if scanning through a bunch of files.

Answer (score 1):

Other (for me) useful commands are J, K, that works as j, k, but do not stop scrolling at the begin or end of file: it is useful because I often use the terminal border as a visual marker.

As a note, they seem to be undocumented, afaik.

Next, I use less to pipe together zipped and not zipped file (it works thanks to lesspipe), as in `less /var/log/dpkg.log* | less`

Answer (score 1):

Not much of a list, but nonetheless quite useful. Just search through man pages by jumping back and forth to matched (case-insensitive) expressions.

```
# use n or shift-n to cycle through the matches
man bash | less -Ip 'parameter expansion'
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the adjustable horizontal scroll option, i.e. prepend the left/right arrow key with a number and `less` will scroll that number of columns from then on, works best with chop-lines option `-S`.

`less` reads command line switches from the `$LESS` variable on startup, here are my preferred switches:

```
$ echo $LESS
-JMQRSi
```

- `-J` add status column on the left, marks columns with search hits.
- `-M` more verbose status line.
- `-Q` no bells.
- `-R` don't convert raw input, lets escape sequences be interpreted.
- `-S` disable line wrapping.
- `-i` case insensitive searching.