# What is the `less` command line option to page to the next file at the end of the current one?

Tags: less, options, pager

I'm sure there used to be an option in `less` which allowed you to page onto the next file after you reached the end of the current file, so you could just keep *space*ing through a bunch of short files without having to keep `:n`ing to get to the next one.

Could someone remind me what it is?

Comment: You might find `cat file1 file2 |less` or `tail -n +1 file1 file2 |less` useful.

Comment: I second the question to the downvoter. I can guess someone had thought that the `-e` option was obvious, but looking at the `manpage`, I can't agree with that.

Comment: It's not worth worrying about @rozcietrzewiacz some people do just downvote for no apparent reason.

Comment: Thanks for the tag correction @Gilles, `paging` refers to virtual memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try the `-e` option.

Comment: Ah, thanks, so what I remembered was a side effect of the `--quit-at-eof` option rather than being an option in it's own right.