# Horizontal scrolling in smaller increments with less -S

Tags: less, scrolling

I'm using `less` to parse HTTP access logs. I want to view everything neatly on single lines, so I'm using `-S`.

The problem I have is that the first third of my terminal window is taken up with metadata that I don't care about. When I use my arrow keys to scroll right, I find that it scrolls past the start of the information that I do care about!

I could just delete the start of each line, but I don't know if I may need that data in the future, and I'd rather not have to maintain separate files or run a script each time I want to view some logs.

#### Example

This line:

> access.log00002:10.0.0.0 - USER_X [07/Nov/2013:16:50:50 +0000] "GET /some/long/URL"

Would scroll to: `ng/URL"`

#### Question

Is there a way I can scroll in smaller increments, either by character or by word?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The only horizontal scrolling commands scroll by half a screenful, but you can pass a numeric argument to specify the number of characters, e.g. typing <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd> scrolls to the right by 4 characters. Less doesn't really have a notion of “current line” and doesn't split a line into words, so there's no way to scroll by a word at a time.

You can define a command that scrolls by a fixed number of characters. For example, if you want <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to scroll by 4 characters at a time:

1. Determine the control sequences that your terminal sends for these key combinations. Terminals send a sequence of bytes that begin with the escape (which can be written `\e`, `\033`, `^[` in various contexts) character for function keys and keychords. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> at a shell prompt: this inserts the escape character literally (you'll see `^[` on the screen) instead of it being processed by your shell, and inserts the rest of the escape sequence. A common setup has <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> send `\eO2D` and `\eO2C` respectively.
2. Create a file called `~/.lesskey` and add the following lines (adjust if your terminal sends different escape sequences):

   ```
   #command
   \eO2D noaction 4\e(
   \eO2C noaction 4\e)
   \eOD noaction 40\e(
   \eOC noaction 40\e)
   ```

   In addition to defining bindings for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>*arrow*</kbd>, you may want to define bindings for <kbd>*arrow*</kbd> alone, because motion commands reuse the numeric values from the last call. Adjust `40` to your customary terminal width. There doesn't appear to be a way to say “now use the terminal width again, whatever it is at this moment”. A downside of these bindings is that you lose the ability to pass a numeric argument to <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> (you can still pass a numeric argument to <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd>).

Then run `lesskey`, which converts the human-readable `~/.lesskey` into a binary file `~/.less` that `less` reads when it starts.

Comment: Very nice explanation, thanks for the details. It seems the normal scrolling with Left/Right get switched to 4 characters also after using Shift + Left/Right, any workaround for this?

Comment: @Slim Not easily I think.

Comment: looks like your edit mentioning binding arrow is good enough (for me at least). thanks!

Answer (score 38):

You can use option "-# " to set the number of columns for horizontal scrolling.

From man page:

> -# or --shift
>   Specifies the default number of positions to scroll horizontally in the RIGHTARROW and LEFTARROW  commands.
>   If the number specified is zero, it sets the default number of positions to one half of the screen width.

Example (set horizontal scrolling to 10 columns):

> less -S -# 10 my_file

Comment: Is there posibility to add this option to some configuration file so I don't have to pass -# 1 option everytime i type the command?

Comment: @Trismegistos Yes, you can set the environment variable in your `~/.bashrc` with `export LESS="-# 1"`

Comment: You can also set a percentage of screen width if the number starts with a decimal point. For example, `-# .25` would scroll by 1/4 of the screen width.

Comment: This answer has the added benefit of being easy to use in an open `less`, by using the command `-` and then specifying `#`, `less` will prompt for `Horizontal shift:` and set the user provided value for the current session. It really ought to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

Type a number, which is the number of columns you want to scroll to, then hit the arrow key.

Source: [List of useful `less` functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31/list-of-useful-less-functions/43728#43728)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use the `most` pager.

In `most`, no-wrap (`-S`) is the default and <kbd>Right</kbd> scrolls one column to the right instead of a half screen. Use <kbd>></kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> to scroll faster.

Another alternative is the `w3m` pager (also one of the best terminal web browsers) where you can use <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd> as well, and <kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd> for finer-grain scrolling (same keys on qwerty keyboards).

Comment: This is not true. More is wrapping be default and there is no -S option.

Comment: @Trismegistos, I'm not talking about `more` (for which there are dozens of implementations), but about [`most`](https://www.jedsoft.org/most/) (by John E. Davis, I'm not aware of any other implementation).