# less in "tail -f mode" and ability to scroll horizontally at the same time

Tags: terminal, console, tail, less

- `less -S` is useful to have horizontal scrolling with arrow keys (like mentioned in [Horizontal scrolling in smaller increments with less -S](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169886/horizontal-scrolling-in-smaller-increments-with-less-s)) instead of breaking long lines into multiple lines
- `less +F`, or alternatively `less` and then <kbd>SHIFT+F</kbd>, is useful to have less behave like `tail -f` with files being appended in realtime

However it seems impossible to have both at the same time.

Question: **Is it possible to have `less` (or another tool) display currently-being-appended files in realtime, and also be able to scroll horizontally long lines (instead of breaking lines into multiple lines)?**

This question comes from  the context of [dealing with Putty with a virtual console width of 2000 characters](https://superuser.com/questions/1663006/putty-ssh-with-a-virtual-console-width-of-2000-characters).

Comment: Hm, what if you have a really long line, so you scroll right; all the shorter lines are now invisible. Now, new lines come in, and less autoscrolls; what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: @MarcusMüller In the case you describe, the only visible line (the super long line) would move up each time a new line arrives. Then you notice "Oh new lines arrived, I'll scroll left to see them".

Answer (score -1):

the easiest solution might be to start `journalctl --no-pager -f` in a scrollable thing like `screen`.

Comment: Just to be sure, why `journalctl`? I'd like to be able to do this for every log file like `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log` or a custom txt file, or even, in real-time, the output of a Python script that takes time to print the output, line after line. See the edit at the end of https://superuser.com/questions/1663006/putty-ssh-with-a-virtual-console-width-of-2000-characters, maybe you will have a super general solution to this problem :)

Comment: ah sorry, I was somewhere with my brain; yeah, then `tail -f /some/log/file` instead of `journalctl --no-pager`

Comment: Is `screen` horizontally scrollable, and does it prevent to break long lines into several lines @MarcusMüller?