# How to get information from "less" stream

Tags: pipe, less

How to get information about the stream displayed by "`less`", especially but not limited to number of lines?

Info: reading this answer [list of less functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31/list-of-useful-less-functions), I did not find out how to know how many lines there are in some command piped to a `less`, for example, "`apt list --installed | less`"

Answer (score 0):

After searching the [manual page for less](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html), I found the shortcut similar to vim's:

> `=` Prints some information about the file being viewed,
> including its name and the line number and byte offset of
> the bottom line being displayed.  If possible, it also
> prints the length of the file, the number of lines in the
> file and the percent of the file above the last displayed
> line.

Also of note are the shell commands:

> `! shell-command`  Invokes a shell to run the shell-command given.  A percent
> sign (%) in the command is replaced by the name of the
> current file. (...) "!" with no shell command simply invokes a
> shell.

Comment: For "apt list --installed | less", END followed by "=" gives how many packages are installed by apt.

Comment: You could activate the "show line numbers" (`-N`) option and go to the end of the file (`G`).